# Using Google Maps API with AngularJS, map not show in center

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using **Google Maps API** in angularJS. I have multiple locations on the map. 
Now I'm trying to view markers in the center of the map, but don't know where is I'm lacking the point.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.mapOptions = {
  zoom: 2,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.3139962480007,47.9858316415248),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  styles:$scope.styles
}

$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('modelmap'), $scope.mapOptions);
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
$scope.markers = [];
$scope.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: '',
  maxWidth: 250
});
var createMarker = function (info){

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: $scope.map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.latitude, info.longitude),
    title: info.address,
    icon: '/assets/Maps-Pin-Place-icon.png'
  });

  var content=' <div class="wwone__map-infobox__inner scrollFix">  <img class="wwone__map-infobox__thumb" src="'+images+'"/> <div class="wwone__map-infobox__inner__heading">'+title+'</div><div class="wwone__map-infobox__inner__info">'+description+'<div class="wwone__map-infobox__inner__info__location"><strong>Address:</strong>'+info.address+'</div></div><a class="wwone__map-infobox__inner__btn btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="openBrnach('+info.id+')">Find out more</a></div> '

  var compiledContent = $compile(content)($scope)

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, scope) {
    return function() {
      scope.infowindow.setContent(content);
      scope.infowindow.open(scope.map, marker);
    };
  })(marker, compiledContent[0], $scope));


  $scope.markers.push(marker);
}
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  createMarker(data[i]);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you want to centre the map when you click on a marker?  Or just when you draw all the markers are you expecting the map to be centred so you can see them all?

Comment: Hi Ducan,i want the map to be centered so we can see them all

Comment: What you need is to have a LatLngBounds object. As you add each marker, extend the bounds with that marker's position.  When you've added all the markers, call fitBounds on the map.

Comment: could you please more explain @duncan

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for a [`fitBounds` function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) to set a viewport, the following example shows how to center and zoom the map so that all markers are getting visible:

```
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++) {
    var marker = createMarker(i);
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  $scope.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Example

```js
angular.module('map-example', [])
  .controller('MapController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {
    function initialize() {
      $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        //zoom: 4,
        //center: { lat: -38.363, lng: 131.044 }
      });

      $scope.cities = [
        { title: 'Sydney', lat: -33.873033, lng: 151.231397 },
        { title: 'Melbourne', lat: -37.812228, lng: 144.968355 },
        {title: 'Perth', lat: -31.9546855,lng: 115.8350292},
        {title: 'Adelaide', lat: -34.9256374,lng: 138.583259}
      ];

      //create a single instance of Info  Window
      $scope.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ''
      });
      //render markers
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++) {
        var marker = createMarker(i);
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
      }
      $scope.map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }


    var createMarker = function (idx) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.cities[idx].lat, $scope.cities[idx].lng),
        map: $scope.map,
        title: $scope.cities[idx].title
      });

      var content = '<button ng-click="showDetails(' + idx + ')" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-eye"></i> Details</button>';
      var compiledContent = $compile(content)($scope)

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        $scope.infowindow.setContent(compiledContent[0]);
        $scope.infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
      });

      return marker;
    };

    $scope.showDetails = function (index) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.cities[index]));
    };

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  });
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 400px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="map-example" ng-controller="MapController"> 
    <div id="map"></div>   
</div>
```